# I want to use GRUB as my MBR instead of Windows MBR....HOW?

Tags: grub2, mbr

I hear that this can b done I just don't know how. Im stil all too new to LINUX

Comment: Please describe your current setup. (dual boot, which operating systems etc.) Moreover, you probably mean you want to use GRUB as a boot loader https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_loader and not as an MBR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record

Comment: Just to clarify - MBR (master boot record) is just first 512 bytes of the drive that holds partition table and bootloader. GRUB is bootloader, thus it can reside in MBR.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use GRUB as default bootloader, you can achieve this by reinstalling GRUB.
You can use the **GParted** tool (available in ubuntu install media) to identify disks and partitions.

If ubuntu is installed in **EFI mode**, boot from ubuntu install media, open a terminal and execute:
(Maybe you have to change the boot order in BIOS / UEFI setup menu afterwards nevertheless.)

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i;
done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Note : `*`= disk | `**` = efi partition | `***` = system partition

If ubuntu is installed in **MBR mode**, boot from ubuntu install media, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sd*
```

Note : `*`= disk | `**` = system partition